# X-Axis label does not appear on chart.js

Tags: javascript, charts, chart.js

Below are the two charts I need to draw. With my configurations, X-Axis labels are not appearing. I have no clue why this is happening.

My X-Axis labels are time series.

```
"scales": {
  "xAxes": [
    {
      "type": "time",
      "unitStepSize": 1,
      "time": {
        "unit": "day"
      },
      "displayFormats": {
        "day": "MMM DD"
      },
      "distribution": "series",
      "gridLines": {
        "display": true,
        "drawBorder": true,
        "drawOnChartArea": true,
        "tickMarkLength": 15
      },
      "stacked": false
    }
  ]
}


"labels": [
  "2020-02-27 12:00:25",
  "2020-02-27 15:00:27"
]
```

Below are the charts in which X-Axis labels are not appearing

Fiddle here : https://jsfiddle.net/dilani_m/2bercd8p/1/

[image]

Fiddle here : https://jsfiddle.net/dilani_m/rmz5kq4t/6/

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You have the correct code and implementation but the data that is being fed to the chart is not enough to render the x-axis labels. For ex. the `labels` below fall on the same day and the `Unit Step Size` is `1 Day`. So by default, the chart does not render the same day label for 2 data points.

```
"labels": [
  "2020-02-27 12:00:25",
  "2020-02-27 15:00:27"
]
```

You can see the working fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/9f2kqj0c/2/)